# getting latest timestamp from 2 joined tables for each row output in select statement

Tags: mysql, select, max, multiple-tables

I have 3 tables as shown below. I want to get a list of member names, ids, together with the latest activity time for each of them, given a particular member name search term.

This 'latest activity time' is the latest time from comparing both the game_record and the eating_record tables.

The desired output is also given below.

member_info table:

```
name     m_id
----     ---- 
john      1
doe       2
johnson   3
```

game_record:

```
time_of_activity      game_id  m_id
----------------      -------  -----
2013-01-20 23:01:00     1         3
2013-01-20 23:01:07     4         1
2013-01-20 23:01:06     1         2
2013-01-20 23:01:05     3         1
```

eating_record:

```
time_of_activity      food_id  m_id
----------------      -------  -----
2013-01-20 23:01:04     1         1
2013-01-20 23:01:03     4         1
2013-01-20 23:01:02     1         2
2013-01-20 23:01:01     3         3
```

desired output when search term is 'john':

```
name     m_id     latest_time
----     ----     -----------
john      1       2013-01-20 23:01:07
johnson   3       2013-01-20 23:01:01
```

---

What I have tried so far:

I can get the first 2 columns by the following query:

```
select name, 
       m_id 
from 
       member_info 
where 
       name like "john%";
```

And I can get the latest_time for a given member by the following query, but I'm not sure how to merge this second query with the first one to get my desired output.

```
select greatest ((select 
                        max(time_of_activity) 
                  from
                      game_record 
                      join 
                          member_info on game_record.m_id = member_info.m_id
                  where member_info.name = "john"),
                 (select 
                        max(time_of_activity) 
                  from
                      eating_record 
                      join 
                          member_info on eating_record.m_id = member_info.m_id
                  where member_info.name = "john"));
```

SQL Fiddle for this is available at: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b70d0/3

P.S. The tables game_record and eating_record have other columns that are particular to games/food that are not included here, since I wanted to simplify and isolate the part where I needed help.

Thank you! :)

Comment: It would be easier for us to help you if you set up a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: Thanks, I've added it to the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `UNION ALL` query to get the `eating_record` and `game_record` times in the same column, then apply an aggregate function to get the `max` time:

```
select m.name,
  m.m_id,
  max(time_of_activity) latest_time
from member_info m
left join
(
  select time_of_activity, m_id
  from game_record
  union all
  select time_of_activity, m_id
  from eating_record
) g
  on m.m_id = g.m_id
where m.name like 'john%'
group by m.name, m.m_id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8f3c5/8).

This could also be written with aggregates in the subquery:

```
select m.name,
  m.m_id,
  max(time_of_activity) latest_time
from member_info m
left join
(
  select max(time_of_activity) time_of_activity, m_id
  from game_record
  group by m_id
  union all
  select max(time_of_activity) time_of_activity, m_id
  from eating_record
  group by m_id
) g
  on m.m_id = g.m_id
where m.name like 'john%'
group by m.name, m.m_id;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8f3c5/10)

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to aggregate each of the tables (games and eating) by member id to get the latest time.  Then, join these together and use the `greatest()` function to get the latest time:

```
select mi.*, greatest(gr.maxtime, er.maxtime) as latest_time
from member_info mi left outer join
     (select m_id, MAX(time_of_activity) as maxtime
      from game_record gr
      group by m_id
     ) gr
     on gr.m_id = mi.m_id left outer join
     (select m_id, MAX(time_of_activity) as maxtime
      from eating_record er
      group by m_id
     ) er
     on er.m_id = mi.m_id
```